# LNK2019 error: Unable to run a function

Tags: linker-errors, lnk2019

I'm having difficulty with my program. I am not nearly finished, but just debugging this, I am receiving an error:

> error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _WinMain@16

I have no idea what is possibly wrong with my program. Could anyone inform me on the possible solution?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;

void PrintHeading (int);          


int main()
{
    int money = 1000; 

    PrintHeading (money);

    return 0;
}


void PrintHeading (int money)
{
   cout << "Welcome to the High-Low Game." << endl;
   cout << "You will initially begin with $ " << money  << "." << endl;
   cout << "You will have six chances to guess a correct";
   cout << " number between 1 and 100." << endl;
   cout << " Let's begin" << endl;
}
```

Comment: Can you post the ACTUAL code?

Comment: You're trying to build a console program as a gui one. A console app will look for a `main` function, while a windows gui one will look for WinMain. You've likely chosen the wrong option when creating the project in your IDE. Go for a console-app.